# A que hora se ejecutará un CRON en linux cuando el comando timedatectl muestra 3 horas diferentes

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Buenas tengo una interrogante quisiera saber si el cron que cree:

```
30 23 * * *  curl -X GET http://localhost/mi_tarea_programada
```

Se ejecutará a la hora asignada, dado que el siguiente comando me da tres horas diferentes.

```sh
$ timedatectl
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco de antemano sus respuestas.

Comment: Supongo que se ejecutará a las 23:30 de hora local. 
SIn embargo puedes hacer la prueba de escribir en un archivo a cierta hora y ver si se ejecuta

Comment: Gracias hice un ejemplo sencillo para que se ejecute  
33 9 * * * echo "hola mundo" > /home/debian/prueba.txt
mas no se ejecuto, el que si se ejecuto fue
34 13 * * * echo "hola mundo" > /home/debian/prueba.txt. La hora UTC fue la que prevalecio al final

Comment: Pues interesante observción, entonces se esta ejecutando al horario universal?

Comment: Si UTC es la que se esta ejecutando, esto hubiera hecho que nunca se ejecute mi cron al final del dia si no al principio del siguiente.

Comment: Gracias @Vichoko ahora configurare mi cron 4 horas antes para que se ejecute correctamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es normal que aparezcan 3 zonas horarias, sin embargo el siempre ejecutará `Local time`, y el `Time zone`

En tu caso se ejecutará a las ***23:30: America/La paz***

### Conceptos

**Local Time:** La hora oficial en un país o área.

**Time zone:** Una de las muchas partes iguales en que se divide el mundo. En cualquier lugar dentro de cada parte, el punto particular del día es el mismo, y está una hora delante o detrás de eso en las partes a cada lado:

**UTC:** El tiempo universal coordinado o UTC es el principal estándar de tiempo por el cual el mundo regula los relojes y el tiempo. Es uno de los varios sucesores estrechamente relacionados con el tiempo medio de Greenwich.

¡Espero haya sido de ayuda!